# Calculate difference in days in one single column based on the values in another column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have a pandas df (called df2) like this:

```
id | orderdate |
___________________
123|2020-11-01 |
123|2020-08-01 |
233|2020-07-01 |
233|2020-11-04 |
444|2020-11-04 |
444|2020-05-03 |
444|2020-04-01 |
444|2020-11-25 |
```

The values of orderdate are datetime with the format '%Y%m%d'. They represent orders of a client. I want to calculate the delta time between the first order and the second one for each id (each client).

I come up with:

```
for i in list(set(df2.id)):
  list_sorted=list(set((df2.loc[df2['id']==i, 'orderdate'] ))) 
  list_sorted= sorted(list_sorted) #get sorted list of the order dates in ascending order
  min_list= list_sorted[0] # first element is first order
  
  df2.loc[df2['id']==i, 'First Order']= min_list

  if len(list_sorted)>1:
    penultimate_list= list_sorted[1]
    df2.loc[df2['id']==i, 'Second Order']= penultimate_list # second element is second order


    df2.loc[df2['id']==i, 'Delta orders']= min_list - penultimate_list #calculate delta


    
  
  else:
    df2.loc[df2['id_user']==i, 'Delta orders']= None
```

My expected outcome is:

```
id | orderdate | First Order | Second Order| Delta Orders
______________________________________________
123|2020-11-01 |2020-08-01   | 2020-11-01  | 92 days
123|2020-08-01 |2020-08-01   | 2020-11-01  | 92 days
233|2020-07-01 |2020-07-01   | 2020-11-04  | 126 days
233|2020-11-04 |2020-07-01   | 2020-11-04  | 126 days
444|2020-11-04 |2020-04-01   | 2020-05-03  | 32 days
444|2020-05-03 |2020-04-01   | 2020-05-03  | 32 days
444|2020-04-01 |2020-04-01   | 2020-05-03  | 32 days
444|2020-11-25 |2020-04-01   | 2020-05-03  | 32 days
```

It works but I feel like it's cumbersome. Any easier way to do it?

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: I will add it in a moment

Comment: @coelidonum [jfyi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: thank you, done @DanilaGanchar

Comment: For id 444, shouldn't the second order be 2020-05-03 ?

Comment: @Psidom sorry my bad

Answer (score 1):

Slightly different from what you want, but it's a start:

```py
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

data = StringIO(
"""id|orderdate
123|2020-11-01 
123|2020-08-01 
233|2020-07-01 
233|2020-11-04 
444|2020-11-04 
444|2020-05-03 
444|2020-04-01 
444|2020-11-25 """)

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep='|')

df['orderdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['orderdate'], infer_datetime_format=True)
df = df.sort_values(['id', 'orderdate'], ascending=False)

def date_diff(df):
    df['order_time_diff'] = (df['orderdate'] - df['orderdate'].shift(-1)).dt.days
    df = df.dropna()
    return df

# this calculates all order differences
df.groupby('id').apply(date_diff)

# this will get the data as requested
df.groupby('id', as_index=False).apply(date_diff).groupby('id').tail(1)
```